# How to program/design LTC3807 step down controller

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

I got a project at the university and I am supposed to design a power source using a [LTC3807](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc3807.html). I think this is quite challenging since I have no prior experience with designing electronics (I am just a student after all). I cant find any tutorials on the web and the documentation is hard to understand.

The requirements for the power source is 5 V input and it should deliver 1 V ±30 mV and up to 2 A output.

I am quite unsure where to start and I have not found any answers form the documentation yet.

The simulation program I will be using is LTSpice.

Does any of you have any tip about how to get started?

Comment: VinFurr - Hi, As you are new here, please read the [tour] & [help] to see the main site rules and how Stack Exchange differs from typical discussion forums. || This site works best with [specific, detailed questions.](/help/how-to-ask). Currently, it's difficult to see where you are stuck *specifically*. If you are unfamiliar with LTSpice, I would focus on learning that (many online & YT tutorials) before getting into this design. You said "*the documentation is hard to understand*" - *which* documentation? || Please [edit] your question to add specific details of the help needed. Thanks.

Comment: Without prior experience the best way to get started is to obtain an evaluation board. Or at least study the documents and reference schematics. Check out the [DC2221A](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/dc2221a.html). You will not get around reading the documentation yourself thoroughly. If you have a specific question, feel free to ask here.

Comment: If you don't have an efficiency or size requirement, use a low frequency (LTC3807 can run at 50 kHz), the design will be easier. The layout of a power converter is critical, there are diagrams in the datasheet that show the high-current paths; these should be short and thick. The inductor is critical, make sure that it has a high enough saturation current.

Comment: The data sheet has circuit examples. Simulate one of those to get a feel and then move the simulation design towards your goal.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the [data sheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3807fa.pdf)
2. Buy the [DC2221A evaluation board](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Analog-Devices/DC2221A?qs=YCa%2FAAYMW03e%252B4iYZ0lxWQ%3D%3D)
3. Download the [user guide](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/DC2221AF.PDF)
4. Change R5 and R7 as a 1:0.8 voltage divider, which will result in a 1 V out, as explained in page 12 of the spec sheet